# Compiler (NetBeans) failed...JNI error has occurred

Tags: java, netbeans

I am teaching myself java. I am currently working on classes and java. I wrote this code but I got this error:

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" C:\Users\Wiliez\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I don't understand why I couldn't compile. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
public class RectArea {
public static void main(String[]args)
{    int myArea = new areaFormula(6,8).getArea();    
   System.out.println(myArea);

}
 }

public class areaFormula {
public int legnth, width;
public areaFormula(int leg, int wid)
        {
            legnth = leg;
            width = wid;
        }
public int getArea()
{
    return legnth*width;
}
```

}

Comment: The problem is not in your code

Comment: Why couldn't it compile then? I tried to run a simple 'Hell World' program and it ran successfully.

Comment: There is an error in your code, but the compiler should notify you about it, not crash like this.